# Extracting components of a filename

Tags: strings, ruby

I have a string `str ="/Users/user/Desktop/task/U6342_Account_20150112.txt"`

I need return only `U6342_Account_20150112` as an array `['U6342','Account','20150112']`

I did

```
str.split('/')[-1].gsub('.txt','').split('_')
```

which gives me `['U6342','Account','20150112']`

Is there any more convenient solution to do it?

Answer (score 5):

The string looks like a filename, so you should use the library functions for handling file paths instead of rolling your own.

```
File.basename(str, '.txt').split('_')
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like 200_success's answer, and that's what I'd use for this specific situation, but here's an alternative that's flexible for other situations, using a regexp:

```
str.match(/([^\/_]+)_([^_]+)_([^_]+).txt/).captures
```

Each piece you want is captured by a parentheses group, and we turn it into the array you want by calling `captures` on the match result.

Comment: Flexible? I see only three captures. You probably want recursive regex.

Comment: good point, basically i was just saying regex + captures solves lots of these kinds of problems